# How can I install go mobile and have it work on windows?

Tags: windows, go, gomobile

I am having issues installing gomobile on windows with the command : 
`go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile`

It doesn't give me any error but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. When trying to execute gomobile afterwards I get the error:

`'gomobile' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured the PATH where the go executable is differs from GOPATH. To find what my GOPATH was, I used the command

`go env GOPATH`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the path to gomobile location to your PATH variable?

Check if it is included with batch command

```
set PATH
```

Comment: Where is the path to downloaded packages ? I thought it would be in $GOPATH/bin as the go command

Comment: depends if u ran `go build`, otherwise it is in src/golang.org - etc

Comment: There is nothing like src/golang.org :/